# Open Safari from app and then get alert to open app again in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, safari, url-scheme

I have a requirement where when user click on login button on app. App should open login page in Safari and once the user logs in, they should get a alert to open the app again. How can I achieve it in Swift? I got this below code to open the link in Safari:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.myloginpage.com") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}
```

But how do I come back to app once user logs in? I want to check if the login was successful or not. If it was successful, there should be an alert to open the app again. Otherwise give the appropriate login error in Safari.

Any suggestions are most welcome. And thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it requirement to open it only in Safari or it just need to be open somehow(for example UIWebView)?

Comment: This is iPad app, And for login we want to use authentication certificate which is already stored in iPad. So if we do it through Safari, safari automatically checks if auth certificate is there or not. If its there then you select your certificate and no need to enter id and password. But if cert is not there then you enter id and password.

Comment: You need to dig in JavaScript to be able to show an alert, but yes, don't know how to handle it from Safari, but WKWebView or UIWebView way - won't be difficult.

Comment: not possible i guess , based on your requirement i guess best way to use inapp webview to manage this scenario , that would be ideal .

Comment: Can we use auth certificate stored in iPad using UIWebView or WKWebView? Main purpose is to avoid user to login again and again. And use auth cert stored in settings.

Comment: I guess you should look at `SafariViewController` API as it supports cookies. But it available only since iOS 9.